# pivot name error when using variables, why?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I made a macro which does a few copy-paste, and change the filter on the pivot table. Now, there are quite a few pivots, with the same filter to be changed (a date), so I want to make a variable for them.

So the macro works without variables, but when I put:

```
Dim x,y as Date
x = "2020/9/1"
y = 2020/8/20"
```

And then put it into the pivot name -I cant copy the full code, nor the parts, because they are on virtual deskop for work.

```
Activesheet.PivotTables("pivottable3").PivotSelect "'2020/9/1' text" _
xlDataAndLabel, True
```

and I changed this to:

```
Activesheet.PivotTables("pivottable3").PivotSelect "'x' text" _
xlDataAndLabel, True
```

and I get an error saying this name doesn't exist. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Couple of things. When you put a variable inside double quotes it also becomes a string. `"'2020/9/1' text"` can be written as `"'" & "2020/9/1" & "' text"` and then to `"'" & x & "' text"` :). Also `Dim x,y as Date` should be `Dim x as String ,y as String`

Comment: Ohh, I will try running it with these changes, thanks a lot :) @SiddharthRout

Comment: The problem is tho, that I also need these variables somewhere else as date, can't I just convert them into strings at the pivot name? @SiddharthRout

Comment: `cdate(x)` will give you date. Alternatively you can declare the variable as date and then use it as a string. Choice is yours